# How to write $A=\{...,A_{-2},A_{-1},A_{0},A_{1},A_{2},...\}$ using the union notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, index-notation

Let, $A_m$ where $m\in \mathbb Z$ be the set $\{(m,n):n\in\mathbb Z\}$.For eg. $A_1={...,(1,-2),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),...}$

Now I define the set $A$ to be the collection of all such sets ie. $A=\{...,A_{-2},A_{-1},A_{0},A_{1},A_{2},...\}$. How do I write A using the union notation?

Comment: @Elman:  that is a fine answer

Comment: $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ A_{m} \}$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is not a union of the sets $A_m$. Instead, each $A_m$ is an *element* of the set $A$. With that said, the most natural way to describe the set $A$ is to say that $A = \{A_m : m \in \Bbb Z\}.$